# Django allauth Redirect on Password Change Success

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-allauth, change-password

This question has been brought up before here: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/468

It's closed and is a few years old, which could explain why its not working for me.
I am simply trying to redirect to a different page other than the change password page after the password is successfully changed.

Here is my code, which is not making the page redirect on success.

```
#ursl.py
url(r'accounts/password/change', views.custom_password_change),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))
...

#views.py
from allauth.account.views import PasswordChangeView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class CustomPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    print("Getting Here")
    @property
    def success_url(self):
        print('Inside Success')
        return '/unknown/'

custom_password_change = login_required(CustomPasswordChangeView.as_view())
```

After submitting a password change, my terminal is printing "Getting Here" so it is definitely getting to that custom view. But its not printing "Inside Success".

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Note that "Getting Here" is printed when the module is loaded and the class is defined, not when the view runs.

Comment: You are missing the trailing slash in the regex -  `r'^accounts/password/change/$'` would be better. You have missed out `name='account_change_password'` as well. I don't think that will fix the problem though.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but same result.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I have exactly the same isssue.

Answer (score 0):

`success_url` is a property, not a method.  So you can either do:

```py
class CustomPasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    success_url = '/unknown/'
```

Or, if you need dynamic URLs (say, with access to User), you can override `get_success_url()`, a class method that basically just returns the `success_url` property.  An example of that below.

```py
class CustomPasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    """
    Overriding Allauth view so we can redirect to profile home.
    """
    def get_success_url(self):
        """
        Return the URL to redirect to after processing a valid form.

        Using this instead of just defining the success_url attribute
        because our url has a dynamic element.
        """
        success_url = reverse('users:user-detail',
                              kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})
        return success_url
```